Serilog console logging with ThreadId
I have a console application with Target framework 8.0.
I would like to log ThreadId to console output of my serilog log. ThreadId is getting logged to json file but in console it does not log ThreadId.
Below is my configuration,


{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.Async" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "Console",
              "Args": {
                "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
                "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
                "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} <s:{SourceContext}>{NewLine}{Exception}"
              }
            },
            {
              "Name": "File",
              "Args": {
                "path": "logs/schedular_log_.json",
                "rollingInterval": "Day",
                "shared": true,
                "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
                "retainedFileCountLimit": 7,
                "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "WithThreadId", "FromLogContext", "WithExceptionDetails" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "Schedular"
    }
  }
}



Below is the result in Console log,


[13:29:12 INF] {"Id": "bb497c8e-9e92-4981-9c98-d3e94ed1b009", "Name": "Mat0", "Created": "2024-04-01T13:29:12.0955808+05:30", "Description": "MatDescription0", "$type": "Material"} <s:>
[13:29:12 INF] {"Id": "98ccbe47-e62a-406a-9eb2-01c7314131e9", "Name": "Mat1", "Created": "2024-04-01T13:29:12.2064649+05:30", "Description": "MatDescription1", "$type": "Material"} <s:>



But in my json file log, I get the below result,


{"Timestamp":"2024-04-01T13:29:12.2068098+05:30","Level":"Information","MessageTemplate":"{@Material}","Properties":{"Material":{"Id":"aac4815f-5ea1-4527-9558-6f0d868cd41c","Name":"Mat7","Created":"2024-04-01T13:29:12.2068090+05:30","Description":"MatDescription7","_typeTag":"Material"},"ThreadId":1,"Application":"Schedular"}}
{"Timestamp":"2024-04-01T13:29:12.2068150+05:30","Level":"Information","MessageTemplate":"{@Material}","Properties":{"Material":{"Id":"25944fb5-a50a-4b74-b561-79c775fadd2b","Name":"Mat8","Created":"2024-04-01T13:29:12.2068147+05:30","Description":"MatDescription8","_typeTag":"Material"},"ThreadId":1,"Application":"Schedular"}}
{"Timestamp":"2024-04-01T13:29:12.2068182+05:30","Level":"Information","MessageTemplate":"{@Material}","Properties":{"Material":{"Id":"6d59c4a6-ba2d-46c8-b3ce-f7ccd7dfff9c","Name":"Mat9","Created":"2024-04-01T13:29:12.2068181+05:30","Description":"MatDescription9","_typeTag":"Material"},"ThreadId":1,"Application":"Schedular"}}



Notice ThreadId in file log and not in console log. Is there a way to have the console log ThreadId.
I would prefer to configure through json only.

You need to add Serilog.Enrichers.Thread and  Serilog.Enrichers.Process nuget package. Change your appsettings.json file as shown below. I have added  "Serilog.Enrichers.Thread", "Serilog.Enrichers.Process", into "Using" parameter value.
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File",  "Serilog.Enrichers.Thread","Serilog.Sinks.Async" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "Console",
              "Args": {
                "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
                "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
                "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} <s:{SourceContext}>{NewLine}{Exception}"
              }
            },
            {
              "Name": "File",
              "Args": {
                "path": "logs/schedular_log_.json",
                "rollingInterval": "Day",
                "shared": true,
                "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
                "retainedFileCountLimit": 7,
                "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "WithThreadId", "FromLogContext", "WithExceptionDetails" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "Schedular"
    }
  }
}

You need to add ".Enrich.WithThreadId()" into your serilog logger configuration.
var appLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configFile)
                .Enrich.WithThreadId()
                .Enrich.WithProcessId()

//.Enrich.WithThreadName()
.Enrich.FromLogContext()
.CreateLogger();

